# In eclipse API, How to get IFile from file that locate outside project or workspace

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.4

I want to create IFile interface to open file that locate outside project or workspace.

How to get IFile interface?

Regards,
Simon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_on_a_file_outside_the_workspace%3F

You can create a *linked resource*:

```
IPath location = new Path(name);
IFile file = project.getFile(location.lastSegment());
file.createLink(location, IResource.NONE, null);
```

Or, if you can use the EFS interface (since Eclipse 3.3), you can use that instead of IFile.

Comment: We have been using EFS to get files that are outside the workspace, it has worked nicely for us.