# Add/Find File to IProject as IFile (Eclipse GUI)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the Eclipse platform to develop a GUI in the form of a Workbench (analogous to using Eclipse). Users open projects, which contain files of a certain type (not Java files - the files are unique to the project, but are just text files), and edit the files using the Workbench. Currently, projects are also directory-specific. This already all exists and is quite functional.

We are, however, adding functionality to the tool; one of the desired functionalities is to be able to import packages/modules from other directories (which is done with import statements; the directory paths are specified in a preferences file). I have been able to do this on the functional level - e.g., with the internal data structures - but I'm struggling with adding these files to the "IProject".

Consider an example. We have one directory, ./foo, which contains a set of text files. There are package statements in these files; let's say they're all also "package foo" to make it simpler.

We have another directory, ./bam, which has another set of text files (package bam). We want package bam to import package foo. As I said, the building of the internal data structures here is already working.

The difficulty is with the interactive Workbench version-  actually adding the files from ./foo to the IProject. This is the way I was recognizing the files from ./bam (when projects were based on directories).

```
IFile bam1 = (IFile) getProject().findMember(bamSource.getPath())
```

"BamSource", here, might be "/bam/bam1.extension". This works fine. But when I try something like:

```
IFile foo1 = (IFile) getProject().findMember(fooSource.getPath())
```

"find-Member" returns a null value. This, obviously, is problematic.

My question, then, is: how can I add or create a new IFile within the existing IProject, such that "findMember" would return the actual IFile?

I've tried creating an IFile separately:

```
 IPath fooPath = new Path(fooSource.getPath());
 IFile test = getProject().getFile(fooPath);
```

I also tried creating a link with that file (as suggested here: [In eclipse API, How to get IFile from file that locate outside project or workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624897/in-eclipse-api-how-to-get-ifile-from-file-that-locate-outside-project-or-worksp)):

```
 test.createLink(fooPath, 1, monitor);
```

Any suggestions? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. You can't create an IFile that is not in the project folder structure. `createLink` can be used to create a link to a file not in the project folders but the link itself must be in the project.

Comment: So if I create a link, how do I add the link to the project? Or how do I add an IFile to the project folder structure?

Comment: The answer you reference shows how to create a link in a project.

Comment: I know, as I mentioned, I tried to do that, but it didn't work / wasn't what I wanted.